# Mysql deadlock Unexpected

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-deadlocks

I am experiencing a deadlock in my stored procedure and I cannot for the life of me figure out why that is

Here is the part of my procedure where I think the deadlock is happening

```
-- if the taskId doesnt exist in the task execution table for a particular month year, taskId and companyId combination then add it in
if NOT exists (select id from T_EXECUTIONS where usertask_id = userTaskId and org_id = orgId and month=currentMonth and year = currentYear)
Then
     insert into T_EXECUTIONS(operations_performed, success_operations, failure_operations, month, year, org_id, usertask_id, created_date, updated_date)
            values(0,0,0,currentMonth, currentYear, orgId, userTaskId, now(), now());
END IF;

-- Update the task execution entry for this month, year, companyId and userTaskid
if isSuccess Then
        update T_EXECUTIONS set operations_performed = operations_performed + operationsPerformed, success_operations = success_operations + operationsPerformed, updated_date=now() WHERE usertask_id=userTaskId and org_id = orgId and month=currentMonth and year = currentYear;
else
        update T_EXECUTIONS set operations_performed = operations_performed + operationsPerformed, failure_operations = failure_operations + operationsPerformed, updated_date=now() WHERE usertask_id=userTaskId and org_id = orgId and month=currentMonth and year = currentYear;
END IF;
```

From the DB logs this is what I am seeing

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
 ------------------------
 2015-05-12 19:35:04 2afa9066b700
 *** (1) TRANSACTION:
 TRANSACTION 23099124, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
 mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
 LOCK WAIT 10 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 246 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
 MySQL thread id 1947206, OS thread handle 0x2afa90b7f700, query id 223242109 10.20.0.197 beta_v1_master update
 insert into T_EXECUTIONS(operations_performed, success_operations, failure_operations, month, year, org_id, usertask_id, created_date, updated_date)
                                       values(0,0,0, NAME_CONST('currentMonth',5),  NAME_CONST('currentYear',2015),  NAME_CONST('org_id',353722),  NAME_CONST('userTaskId',75801), now(), now())
 *** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
 RECORD LOCKS space id 2468 page no 4 n bits 192 index `fk_execution_org_id` of table `beta_v1_db`.`T_EXECUTIONS` trx id 23099124 lock_mode X insert intention waiting
 Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
  0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

 *** (2) TRANSACTION:
 TRANSACTION 23099125, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
 mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
 10 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 246 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
 MySQL thread id 1947212, OS thread handle 0x2afa9066b700, query id 223242110 10.20.0.197 beta_v1_master update
 insert into T_EXECUTIONS(operations_performed, success_operations, failure_operations, month, year, org_id, usertask_id, created_date, updated_date)
                                       values(0,0,0, NAME_CONST('currentMonth',5),  NAME_CONST('currentYear',2015),  NAME_CONST('org_id',353722),  NAME_CONST('userTaskId',75786), now(), now())
 *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
 RECORD LOCKS space id 2468 page no 4 n bits 192 index `fk_execution_org_id` of table `beta_v1_db`.`T_EXECUTIONS` trx id 23099125 lock mode S
 Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
  0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;
```

I cant figure out why deadlock is occuring for this particular block of code.
Should I perform this sort of task in a differnt way?

Cheers
Damien

Comment: Why not use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` btw, you should **always** add `LIMIT 1` if you only need to look for or update a single row. So MySQL stops looking for another possible row when it hits the first.

Comment: thanks I wasnt aware of that LIMIT 1 notion - im a not a mysql developer by trade. I dont think the INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY will work for me for a few various reasons. Is the mysql I provided poorly formed or something?

Comment: Please show a structure of T_EXECUTIONS table, especially indexes created on this table and auto_increment fields.